# file_put_contents(filepath/file) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, linux, file-io

I have explored and taken few tips from related forums here but still I am not able to clear my problem so I am posting it kindly help me. Thanks to all.

I have shared linux hosting and recently they offered an upgrade and I accepted. Unfortunately, they claim my php application should be fine tuned to php version 5.3. This application of mine was working great in earlier server which was php version 5.2. The problem is file permission denied error when I try to register a login or logout history or ANY such file write.  I have highlighted following code because it is the first error encountering sample . Here is my sample code.

I specifically use file_put_contents and file_read_contents. Here is my sample code below.

```
// define('DATA_PATH_MEMB', dirname( __FILE__) ."/../docs/vendor/"."data/_memdata/");
// above constant is an include file 
function updateLogins() {
  $user = $_SESSION['thisuserName'];
  $filejsonread = DATA_PATH_MEMB.$user.".dat";
  $filejsonwrite = DATA_PATH_MEMB.$user.".dat";  
  $updateDataArr = json_decode(file_get_contents($filejsonread),true);
    $timenow =  array( "datetimestamp" => date("d-m-Y h:i") );
    array_push($updateDataArr["useracess"][0]["history"]["logins"], $timenow);
    array_push($updateDataArr["useracess"][0]["history"]["logouts"], $timenow);
    file_put_contents($filejsonwrite, json_encode($updateDataArr), LOCK_EX);    
 }
```

I get following error pointing the file_put_contents as

> file_put_contents(/home/mydomain/public_html/includes/../docs/gbo/data/_memdata/someusr.dat) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: Permission denied

I asked them if my user account be part of the group that the file is assigned to with write permission. My dir is 755 and my files are 644 and in earlier server with all sincerity my application worked. I dont know what to do if cant write into any file.

I tried this

```
echo exec('whomai'); // it displays nobody
```

I am a programmer not administrator. What should I ask them or correct myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file has,

```
-rw-r--r-- (644) — Only the owner has read and write permissions; the group and others can read only.
```

This permission status means the owner of the file has write permission but not anyone else. While your PHP file which is trying to write to this file runs as a different user than your user name.

Thus the error, Apache is not able to write on this file. But if you `ssh` to your server and `vi -file`. You will be able to write that file without problem.

Solution :

Give Apache write permission to this file. `chown` this file and give Apache the ownership.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I really appreciate. As such my application creates and updates files on the fly. I will comeback and accept your answer once they oblige.

Comment: Unfortunately, my server guy did not accept but I go with you.

Comment: So, did I answer you correctly...because it is completely okay if this answer is incorrect :). But, from my experience as system admin as well as programmer. I can tell that your issue has to be the one I explained. Btw. Thanks for accepting my answer.

Comment: I am still stuck. My new php 5.3.4 setting Apache Handler PHP configuration user/group setting is 'nobody' offfered by virtual Host provider and they say it is normal of Apache to run like 'nobody'. But my application is failing and continue to get the error of Permission Denied. I have only CPanel access and I do not know how to give Apache write permission to my account so that my php applications can write to files. Kindly help.

Comment: I would love to help but I dont have access to your server. To practise these bits, I opened a free account with Amazon AWS and created a linux box for practise. I suggest you to do the same. I am developer my self...but I wanted to learn little bit of System Admin. And I suggest you the same :). Once you will setup Linux on AWS and get your hands on...it will be easy to communicate with your System Admin people. Hope this will help

Comment: thanks for your advise I will try it out. Hours ago, I found with a test user file, that if the file is 666 my application runs(no file permission denied error) but not with 644. But this change I did using CPanel. But my program is more of a CMS where file are dynamically created, updated and I cannot or don't know how many files are created to be updated with permission. I had put again a request to Host to check on this. Worst case before writing I have to change ownership and after writing roll-back ownership, but will this not defeat the purpose of having server control operations.

Comment: I just substituted with test files, it looks the file_put_contents and file_get_contents is able read and write into new file in the same path as above but not for those migrated data files.  Should I use any touch command recursively with data directory or something. Any thing I am missing here.

Comment: I would not use 666, it is not very secure. You can chmod all the files and directory to 744 which only allows group and users to read and write permission. More Info : http://superuser.com/questions/295591/what-is-the-meaning-of-chmod-666

Answer (score 0):

if you have enforcing set to active this could be a problem.

Try (On your Linux shell):
[root@***]# setenforce 0

solved it for me.